# Regex - How do I get this value from a line of a text file?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I'm so very poor at preg_match, which I think is the function required here. I'm trying to get the time value (always 3 decimals I think) from this line in a text file:-

```
frame=    42 q= 38.0 f_size=    909 s_size=        1kB time= 1.400 br=   218.2kbits/s avg_br=     5.2kbits/s type= I
```

So, in that example I want to get 1.400. Any guidance much appreciated, I find regex truly, truly baffling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/time\s*=\s*(\d+\.\d{3})/',$str,$matches)) {
   $time = $matches[1];
}
```

Just incase you are not sure about the number of decimal digits or the existence of the decimal point you can do:

```
if(preg_match('/time\s*=\s*(\d+\.?\d+)/',$str,$matches)) {
   $time = $matches[1];
}
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/CRmBk)

Comment: hmmm, sorry but that one is by far not the best solution of the posted ones it would fail if time is over 9.999 and if its under 1.000 ...

Comment: don't mention it just wanted to make sure @WiseDonkey knows what he is fetching, and what not, btw. `time\s*=\s*(\d+\.\d+|\d+)` should probably do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Or to get all values at once:

```
preg_match_all("/(\w+)=\s*(\d[\d.]*)/", $str, $uu);
$values = array_combine($uu[1], $uu[2]);
```

would give you:

```
Array
(
  [frame] => 42
  [q] => 38.0
  [f_size] => 909
  [s_size] => 1
  [time] => 1.400
  [br] => 218.2
  [avg_br] => 5.2
)
```

Comment: Thanks mario, put codaddict as correct answer as it was and the first. But, this is most helpful for users.

Comment: @WiseDonkey: No worries, you should always pick the most appropriate answer for *your* case. Any alternatives are just for others who stumble upon it.

Answer (score 2):

use `time=[^\d]*([\d]+\.[\d]+|[\d]+)` :

```
$string1 = "frame=    42 q= 38.0 f_size=    909 s_size=        1kB time= 1.400 br=   218.2kbits/s avg_br=     5.2kbits/s type= ";
$string2 = "frame=    42 q= 38.0 f_size=    909 s_size=        1kB time= 400 br=   218.2kbits/s avg_br=     5.2kbits/s type= ";

preg_match('#time=[^\d]*([\d]+\.[\d]+|[\d]+)#',$string1,$matches1);
preg_match('#time=[^\d]*([\d]+\.[\d]+|[\d]+)#',$string2,$matches2);

print $matches1[1]; // prints 1.400
print $matches2[1]; // prints 400
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$match = preg_match('/time=\\s*(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)/', $row, $matches);

$time = $matches[1];
```

What this does is match:

- the literal string `time=`
- followed by zero or more spaces ( `\s*` )
- followed by one or more digits ( `\d+` )
- followed *optionally* by: a dot, then one or more digits ( `(\.\d+)?` )

So it's in fact a little looser than digit-dot-three digits: it will match any integer or floating point number, with any number of decimal digits.